# Exiting the Loop with out Executing of map or flatMap

Tags: java, project-reactor

While Iterating the Flux code i am getting issue exiting to the end of the method.

I have tried all the possibilities but no luck

```java
    Flux ItemInventoryModelFlux = InventoryService .findBIdAndListOfItems(storeId, itemList);
    Mono<Object> obj = storeItemInventoryModelFlux.collectList().flatMap(storeItemInventoryModels -> {
      response.getAdjustedDemand().stream().forEach(adjustedDemand -> {
        if (bpnList.contains(adjustedDemand.getBpn())) {
          if (true) {
            storeItemInventoryModels.stream().forEach(storeItemInventoryModel -> {
              isRegularItem(storeItemModelFlux,bpnList.get(0));
            });
          }
        }
      });
```

This should run to the other method inside the loop but exiting to the end.

Comment: Streams are not designed to not be consumed to the end. Just use a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion i made few changes and its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Flux<T> takeWhile(Predicate<? super T> continuePredicate)` function to specify the "exit" condition. When the predicate that you supply returns `false` you'll stop consuming elements from the original stream.
[Link to Flux javadoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-)